# How to have a fallback route to catch unknown pages in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a set of routes set up like the following:

```
routes: {
  '!/home': 'home',
  '!/home/:page': 'home'
}
```

What I'm wondering is, how do I configure a route such that if the user requests an unknown page I can easily redirect to a static 404.html page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Router (the first two routes are for example):

```
routes: {
  "path/": "objectList",
  "path/:id": "objectItem",
  ":whatever": "notFound"
}
```

The last is the most general route possible, and will pick up everything not recognized by more specific routes.

Comment: ":whatever" will only match up to the first /. Use "*whatever" to match any number of URL components

Comment: *whatever ends up matching all my routes - I want it to be hit only if none of the other urls matched

Comment: What if you're using multiple instances of Backbone.Router? This could pose a problem, as the default route (in this case, `:whatever`) would match any route, thereby preventing a different router instance from attempting to route the request.

Comment: Thanks! @ElfSternberg Are these references available anywhere in the backbone documentation?

Comment: Not that I know of.  That's why there's the annotated source code.  It's better documentation than the documentation.

Comment: I found something useful, if it helps: http://mrbool.com/backbone-js-router/28001

Answer (score 0):

I know that Q was actual BC, but I have webix in my project and they suggest Backbone, so it's actual for me now. Part of working code:

```
var router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "dashboard", // default router must be defined
    "dashboard(/:tab)": "dashboard",
    // ....
    ":foo(/:bar)(/:so)(/:far)": "fallback",
  },
  dashboard: (tab) => workspace('dashboard', {args: [tab]}), // replace it
  fallback: () => router.go(router.routes['']),
  go: function (route, args = []) {
    this.navigate([route, ...args].join("/"), { trigger: true })
  },

}));
```